# Jupyter notebook no start in debian 10

Tags: jupyter, anaconda

Instale anaconda3 en debian 10 y cuando quiero abrir júpyter notebook me surge este mensaje:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/raul/anaconda3/bin/jupyter-notebook", line 11, in
sys.exit(main())
File "/home/raul/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyter_core/application.py", line 268, in launch_instance
return super(JupyterApp, cls).launch_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
File "/home/raul/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 663, in launch_instance
app.initialize(argv)
File "</home/raul/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/decorator.py:decorator-gen-7>", line 2, in initialize
File "/home/raul/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 87, in catch_config_error
return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/raul/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 1720, in initialize
self.init_webapp()
File "/home/raul/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 1482, in init_webapp
self.http_server.listen(port, self.ip)
File "/home/raul/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/tcpserver.py", line 151, in listen
sockets = bind_sockets(port, address=address)
File "/home/raul/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/netutil.py", line 174, in bind_sockets
sock.bind(sockaddr)
OSError: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address
```

Probe algunas sugerencias de la SO en inglés cambiando el archivo de configuración de júpiter pero no logré nada. Se agradece cualquier ayuda.

Comment: Saludos, estás en SO en español, por favor traduce tu pregunta o es  casi seguro termine cerrada

Comment: Y si pruebas ejecutar jupyter con ```jupyter notebook --ip=127.0.0.1``` ?

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque  no versa sobre un problema específico de programación tal como se expone en el [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1):

Acabo de encontrar la solución y quiero compartirla para que le sirva a principiantes como lo soy yo.

Entrando al jupyter_notebook_config.py en el archivo .jupyter edité una línea quitando el númeral (#) o "almohadilla" sacando el 127.0.0.1 y sustituyéndolo por '0.0.0.0'.

```
## The IP address the notebook server will listen on.
c.NotebookApp.ip = '0.0.0.0'
```

Esto permitió que arranque desde anaconda y desde la terminal.
Espero que le sirva a alguien.

Comment: Saludos, entonces está es la respuesta que debe ir marcada como aceptada